# Safe to send heart rate up quickly?

Tags: health, heart-rate

I commute by bike. After sitting at my programming job all day, I'm pretty wound up and I start off my trip home with a mighty sprint that leaves me panting, and with a high heart rate.

I'm guessing my heart rate goes from 70 to about 170 in 20 seconds or so.

Is this bad? I feel like I can remember being warned before about making my heart rate spike upwards.

Answer (score 2):

Hearth rate is a consequence of how you use your body. It is regulated by **catecholamines** ( a class of hormones that includes **adrenaline** and **noradrenaline** ).

It's not a problem if you do that in such short amount of time. A lot of sports require immediate changes of pace in terms running or cycling.